# What does a compiled version of an outer join look like?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Given a LINQ to Entity query with an outer join...

```
var query = from items in entityDb.TableName
         join requestedBy in entityDb.People on items.RequestedById equals requestedBy.PersonId into requestedByOuter
         from requestedBy in requestedByOuter.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select items;
```

What does the compiled (Lamba expressions) version of such an outer join look like?  Is there any way to see this in the visual studio debugger?

**UPDATE**
To clarify, Jon Skeet explains in his [book](http://manning.com/skeet2/) that query expressions are "compiler translated" to normal C# code before doing "real compilation".  My question is how is the query expression translated to real C# in the case of outer joins?  And, can we see these translations in the debugger or by some other means?

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I updated the question to hopefully clarify what I am looking for.

Comment: You want the lamba expression of a left join?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2009/02/06/converting-linq-queries-from-query-syntax-to-method-operator-syntax.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement:

```
from u in TblUsers
join c in TblCompanies on u.FkCompanyID equals c.PkCompanyID into g
from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
select u
```

Would result in this lamba expression (according to the excellent application [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)):

```
TblUsers
   .GroupJoin (
      TblCompanies, 
      u => u.FkCompanyID, 
      c => c.PkCompanyID, 
      (u, g) => 
         new  
         {
            u = u, 
            g = g
         }
   )
   .SelectMany (
      temp0 => temp0.g.DefaultIfEmpty (), 
      (temp0, x) => temp0.u
   )
```

Comment: This along with @JamieSee comment answer the question.